# Meteor Accounts with different capitalization

Tags: meteor, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, user-accounts

When I include the Meteor accounts package, and the accounts-ui package, the usernames are case sensitive.

If I register as "Liam", then log out and try to log back in as "liam", it doesn't work. I can, however, register a new account with the username "liam".

I would like to change it so usernames are case insensitive, but I am not sure where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are solutions posted within [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/550) issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, try doing something like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.username = user.username.toLowerCase();
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

to make sure that the `username` is always stored in the lower case.

What you'll need to do on the client may be a little more complicated. Somehow, you'll need to ensure that the `username` that is being sent to the server is always transformed to lower case. Not very clean, but probably the easiest way to go would be to patch the `Meteor.loginWithPassword` method, or to convert username to lowercase as the user enters the value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too.

My aim was to have:

- Username is not case sensitive
- Users can choose between Capital and small for the username

  So I decided to store a public-username in profile and the technical username after "lowercase" it.

In my project, authentication is done with e-mail and password, so profile-username is just a profile data than I can publish and display

I hope it will help